# Finding closest date from a list of dates comparing to DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, list, linq, uipath, uipath-studio

I am trying get the closest date from a **list** of `DateTime`. I want to compare the `DateTime` item present in the list to `DateTime.Now` and get the **closest date**.

So far I tried: `DateTime.Compare(item, DateTime.Now)` but this doesn't work in UiPath as I am unable to find Just `DATE` type in the UiPath.

Comment: comparing only by date? not also by time?

Comment: it seems that you are looking for a linq solution. Have you tried solving it with a loop?

Comment: @MongZhu In my case time will be 00:00:00 for all the dates present in the list, So either way I am not considering the time but however I didn't find **Date** format in UiPath so the **DateTime** format was pretty close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq, you can run into an issue with lazy evaluation. In this case since you are using time objects and `DateTime.Now`, that could be a very bad thing, as the Linq expresion may not evaluate for a return value *until the value is required* by other code. This may not be an issue for you, and other users have answered on this post for the Linq version. Otherwise,  the tried and true For loop approach like in the method below will solve the issue, and return a Datetime object for later use.

```cs
public DateTime ReturnClosest(List<DateTime> dateTimes)
{
    //Establish Now for simpler code below
    var now = DateTime.Now;

    //Start by assuming the first in the list is the closest
    var closestDateToNow = dateTimes[0];

    //Set up initial interval value, accounting for dates before and after Now
    TimeSpan shortestInterval = now > dateTimes[0] ? now - dateTimes[0] : dateTimes[0] - now;

    //Loop through the rest of the list and correct closest item if appropriate
    //Note this starts at index 1, which is the SECOND value, we've evaluated the first above
    for (var i = 1; i < dateTimes.Count; i++)
    {
        TimeSpan testinterval = now > dateTimes[i] ? now - dateTimes[i] : dateTimes[i] - now;

        if(testinterval < shortestInterval)
        {
            shortestInterval = testinterval;
            closestDateToNow = dateTimes[i];
        }
    }

    //return the closest Datetime object
    return closestDateToNow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks works fine :D

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything wrong with just subtracting the date times in your list with the datetime.now gives you? it returns a TimeSpan but you can get the seconds from that (all the way down to ms if you want that accuracy). Then just take the absolute value of the difference between the two if you are expecting to receive date times that are in the future in your list of DateTimes. Then use linq to order and grab the first one.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var dates = new List<DateTime> 
        { 
            new DateTime(2014, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(2015, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(2016, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(2017, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(2018, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(2019, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(2020, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(2020, 4, 30),
            new DateTime(2021, 1, 1)

        };

        var minDate = dates.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((now - x).TotalSeconds)).First();


    }
```

Comment: I am using UiPath. However this equation doesn't seem to validate.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two `DateTime` simply using the difference as follows: `TimeSpan interval = DateTime.Now - otherdate;`. Once you have TimeSpans, select the smaller one

Answer (score 0):

In a non-very optimal way you can do it using LINQ, something like:

```
        var dates = new DateTime[]
        {
            new DateTime(2011, 5, 8),
            new DateTime(2011, 5, 9),
            new DateTime(2001, 6, 21)                
        };

        var input = new DateTime(2011, 5, 8, 13, 8, 58);
        var closest = dates
            .Select(x => new { date = x, diff = Math.Abs((x - input).Ticks)})
            .OrderBy(x => x.diff)
            .First();

        Console.WriteLine(closest.date);
```

Output:

```
5/9/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Hey, I am using UiPath and I don't find .Tricks() there

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way using LINQ but has `O(n*log(n))` complexity. [DateTime.Subtraction Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction) subtracts a specified date and time from another specified date and time and returns a time interval. [`TimeSpan.Duration()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.duration) returns a new TimeSpan object whose value is the absolute value of the current TimeSpan object. So, you an just order source value by durations and take first value with [`First()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first).

```
DateTime closestDate = dates.OrderBy(d => (d - DateTime.Now).Duration()).First();
```

There is solution with `O(n)` complexity:

```
var closestDate = (date: new DateTime(), duration: TimeSpan.MaxValue);
foreach (var date in dates)
{
    var duration = (date - DateTime.Now).Duration();
    if (duration < closestDate.duration)
        closestDate = (date, duration);
}
return closestDate.date;
```

Also you can do the same with LINQ and `O(n)` complexity but in an unobvious way:

```
DateTime closestDate = dates
    .Select(d => (date: d, duration: (d - DateTime.Now).Duration()))
    .Aggregate((date: new DateTime(), duration: TimeSpan.MaxValue), (currentClosest, d) => d.duration < currentClosest.duration ? d : currentClosest)
    .date;
```